# How to make recyclerview width larger than the layout width?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I want to make the width of a recyclerView wider than the width of the layout itself so that only a part of the items of the recyclerView could be seen until the user scroll to the left.

I think an image can explain it better:

Each item of the recyclerView have 5 textViews like this:

[image: SS1]

And I want to see only 4 of them until the user scrolls to the left like this:

[image: SS2]

After scrolling, the first textView shouldn't be seen until the user scrolls to the right.

How can I accomplish that? Should I change the item layout to be larger than the screen or the recyclerView?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try using horizontal scrollview for list item and using nested scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be looking for something like this.

[image: Recyclerview inside horizontal scroll view]

1. Embed the RecyclerView (**nestedScrollingEnabled=false**) inside a Horizontal Scrollview
2. List item for Recyclerview should have the **width** set to **wrap_content**

You can checkout this [project on Github](https://github.com/monsterbrain/RecyclerviewTableViewAndroid)